# General-purpose distributed scheduling library for Java

Tags: java, distributed, schedule

I'm looking for some general library for scheduling lots of tasks. The library has to provide ability to split tasks across nodes in cluster, perform load balancing and fault tolerance - so if some node goes down, the tasks for the node has to be distributed across remaining nodes.

I looked at the Hadoop - but look like it will work well for map-reduce tasks. In my case tasks are simply senders of notifications, checkers for object state etc.

Quartz seems to be great - but it's not clear how good is it when it comes down to dispatching events to nodes.

Any other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for [Akka](http://akka.io).

Comment: or for [Redisson scheduler service](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services/#94-distributed-scheduled-executor-service)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Christian that Akka seems like a better fit. Quartz is great for what it does, but its basic building block is a Job that should be executed. It's not going to help you decompose your job into distributable components.

If all your tasks can be decomposed into jobs, then Quartz can help you schedule them, that's what it does best. But if a job needs to decompose into subtasks, then you'll need to use another framework.

Another option might be [spring batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/), depending on your needs.

Comment: For now, it is possible to run one task as "job", but I don't see how quartz can deal with distributed task management and handle cases when one node is down. And it uses polling , so it is needed to configure some sort of database where job has to be stored, this is potential bottleneck. Am I missing something?

Comment: the database is indeed a bottleneck. for distributed tasks, you can configure clustering, but this is somewhat limited

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ProActive](http://proactive.activeeon.com/index.php), a workflow scheduler that integrates well with Java (written in Java).
It supports the features you listed.
It is an open source project, part of OW2.

The following features for instance are available:

- Workflows, ie set of tasks with dependencies and constructs such as loop/if/replication
- Tasks are executed on nodes, i.e agents running on different machines
- Tasks can be restarted automatically upon node failure

[disclaimer] I'm part of Activeeon, the company providing professional support for ProActive[/disclaimer]

Comment: Please read [answer], answer should also include enough information to be useful even if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also try [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), it can handle almost anything you want:)

Comment: what about distributed task processing and cases when one node goes down? Looks like there is no out of the box solution.

Comment: @jdevelop Quatz clustering mode does support fail over